# Laravel database migration Incorrect table definition

Tags: laravel, syntax, migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('materials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',60);
            $table->integer('category_id',10);
            $table->integer('low_bulk',10);
            $table->integer('high_bulk',10);
            $table->integer('order_level',10);
            $table->decimal('unit_price',10,2);
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This schema gives me this following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be
defined as a key
```

Can anyone tell me what should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again like this.

```
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('materials', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name',60);
                $table->integer('category_id);
                $table->integer('low_bulk');
                $table->integer('high_bulk');
                $table->integer('order_level');
                $table->decimal('unit_price',10,2);
                $table->string('description');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

For more details, you can refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#creating-columns).

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of `integer()` is not the length but whether the column should be auto-incrementing. PHP converts `10` to `true` and tries to make all these columns auto-incrementing.

Just remove it, the length doesn't have any effect on MySQL:

```php
Schema::create('materials', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name',60);
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->integer('low_bulk');
    $table->integer('high_bulk');
    $table->integer('order_level');
    $table->decimal('unit_price',10,2);
    $table->string('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: If for some reason the length does need to be defined, here's the syntax: `$table->integer('category_id')->length(10)`